# Как составить условие, содержит ли в себе блок, определенные элементы с классом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

на странице есть `<div id="response">` он при загрузки страницы пустой, но после нажатия по кнопки применить фильтры, по ajax он наполняется (а может и нет)  `<div class="slider__item">`как мне написать такое условие, если `<div id="response">` имеет >= 2 `<div class="slider__item">`, то к `<div id="response">` добавляется класс, если меньше 2, то класс удалить.
Пробовал так, но почему то не работает, это может быть связано с ajax подгрузкой?

```
var div = $('#response').has('.slider__item').index();

        if(div>=0){
            $('#response').addClass('active');
        };
```

Comment: Вам нужно сразу делать селект нужных элементов и смотреть их количество

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно можно сделать [так](https://api.jquery.com/length/)

```
let div = $('#response');

let count = $('.slider__item', div).length;
```

или так

```
let count = $('#response > .slider__item').length;
```

```js
$('#add').on("click", ()=> {  
  let element = document.createElement("div");  // Create with DOM
  $(element).addClass("slider__item");
  $(element).text("Text");
  $('#response').append(element); 
})



$('#count').on("click", ()=> {
  let div = $('#response');
  let element = document.createElement("div");  // Create with DOM
  $(element).addClass("slider__item");
  let count = $('.slider__item', div).length;  
  console.log(count);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="count">Count</button>

<div id="response">

</div>
```

Далее смотрим на количество и делаем что желаете

Comment: let div = $('#response');

 let count = $('.slider__item', div).length;

if(count >= 2 ){
   div.addClass('active');
};
не могу понять почему не работает?

Comment: @DmitriyMedvedkin да именно так

Comment: я смторю в console.loп(count):  и после того как #response содержит 10slider__item, в консоле все равно 0

Comment: @DmitriyMedvedkin Доьавил пример в песочницу

Comment: спасибо большое!